Does having a photographic memory cause issues with copyright law?
Assuming someone has a photographic memory, or a good enough memory to memorize entire copyright-protected works, does memorizing and then writing out verbatim (reproducing) the work, count as "copying"?
I originally asked weakly, because perhaps the answer to this is obvious or simply another infringement so still not allowed, but I am still curious how this is dealt with in writing up the laws.

How would anything not be copied at that point? You have memories from every copyrighted thing you have seen.

memorizing is fine. writing it back out is not. Nor is publicly reciting it.

No.
Simply remembering something does not constitute a copy for copyright purposes.

Ugh. They changed the question a couple of minutes after you answered. They added "and then writing out". Does that change things, since now they've made a tangible copy?

@Barmar Certainly. Writing an exact copy of the original would almost surely be a copyright violation, just as if you had done it medieval monk style.

@Barmar happy to just delete the question, if a mod lets

@ohwilleke medieval monk style? I.e. direct copying by hand? This is still a bit different because it is memorizing, but I hear. I had a feeling it was  just a silly question
